# Custom login page redirected too many times err - Java Spring starter 3.0.6 and Security 6 version

Tags: spring, spring-security

Login page gives too many redirects error.

**Security configuration:**

```
http.securityContext((securityContext) -> securityContext.requireExplicitSave(false))
                .cors().configurationSource(corsConfigurationSource())
                .and().sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and().authorizeHttpRequests((requests) -> requests
                        .requestMatchers("/images/*","/jsp/error**").permitAll()
                ) .formLogin((form) -> form
                        .loginPage("/Login")
                        .defaultSuccessUrl("/Home", true).permitAll()     
                ));         
                return http.build();
            }`
    
    **Controller :**
    `@Controller  @GetMapping(value = "/Login")     
     public String showLoginPage(ModelMap model) {
    return "Login";
    }
```

Could anyone please help to resolve the issue.
I did try few solutions suggested , but no luck.